# Stop iAds from serving testing ads

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, iad

Is it possible to stop iAds from serving testing ads?

I mean even my app is waiting to be approved, is it possible to stop it from serving any testing ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple don't show ads until your app approved.

Comment: The app is approved if the running app was compiled with an app store distribution certificate.